# pam_tally2 add an extra failed login

Tags: security, pam

I am trying to use `pam_tally2` in `/etc/pam.d` galaxy

I change sshd to the following content

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth     required       pam_securetty.so
auth     required       pam_tally2.so deny=3 unlock_time=600
auth     required       pam_env.so
auth     required       pam_unix.so
auth     required       pam_nologin.so
account  required       pam_unix.so
password required       pam_unix.so
session  required       pam_limits.so
session  required       pam_unix.so
session  required       pam_lastlog.so nowtmp
session  optional       pam_mail.so standard
```

I created a test account; before login, I tested the failed login count:

```
pam_tally2 -u tst3402
(empty)
```

now I log in using the correct password (this is done by an `expect` script, password is like `aaa12BBB,` )

```
spawn ssh -l tst3402 172.9.2.1
Password:
No mail.
Last login: Tue Mar 20 14:25:17 2018 from 172.2.2.2
tst3402@hostname:~>

status OK
```

where

- **status OK** is sent by `expect`

I recheck the failure count

```
pam_tally2 -u tst3402
Login           Failures Latest failure     From
tst3402             1    03/20/18 14:25:17  172.2.2.2
```

This implies that after 3 sucessful logins, the account is locked.

### Question

why after a succesful login does `pam_tally2` see 1 failures ?

usual suspect:

- I know I can use ssh keys, but I am under ISAE3420's curse
- using ssh -vvv -l ... I see two exchange .. I should see 2 failures ?

  ```
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  ```
- there is no SELinux
- I didn't find any pam_tally2 question in security.SE

Comment: I see the same behviour with a very similar pam stack. Did you resolve the issue? If you happen to remember how, please add an answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

I am seeing a similar behaviour on one of my machines: using `sudo` with correct password generates an entry in `pam_tally2`'s counter.

### Context

The `pam.d/sudo` entry is the default one, quite simple:

```
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

In `common-auth`, I have added the `pam_tally2.so` line at the top, before the `pam_unix.so` line:

```
auth    required                    pam_tally2.so onerr=fail audit deny=5 unlock_time=900

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure

# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so

# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so

# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional            pam_cap.so
```

### Explanation

The `pam_tally2` man page states (emphasis mine):

> Authentication phase first increments attempted login counter and checks if user should be denied access. If the user is
> authenticated *and the login process continues on call to pam_setcred(3)* it resets the attempts counter.

So, up so far, I believe that the stack does not correctly call `pam_setcred`. No file in `pam.d` has a call to `pam_setcred` (it is not even installed on my system).

### Solution

In the examples, the man-page states (emphasis mine):

> The module does not have to be called *in the account phase* because the
> login calls pam_setcred(3) correctly.

So, if no call to `pam_setcred`, then the module needs to be called in the `account` phase.

I edited `pam.d/common-account` file and added on top:

```
account required                        pam_tally2.so
```

This will reset the counter when the user manages to authenticate.

### TODO

If a user cancels the authentication (e.g. by pressing Ctrl+C when prompted for the password), then this has incremented the counter without decrementing it, so it is undistinguishable from a failed attempt.

Comment: wow !! two years and a half after !! thank you for taking time to write an answer.

Comment: Well, it took enough headbanging to not share this with others. My use case is different than yours, but I hope that the solution is the same. (note that I've changed it from the 1st version, which was wrong)